# coffeescript instance variable undefined

Tags: coffeescript, instance-variables

In the constructor for my class `PostsPager` I set the default value of `@page` to 0, then call render. When I enter render, however, @page is now undefined. Why would this be?

```
class PostsPager
  contructor: (@page=0)->
    render()
    $(window).scroll(@check)

  check: =>
    if @nearBottom()
      @render

  render: =>
    alert @page  # @page = undefined
```

wat

EDIT

The compiled JS

```
PostsPager = (function() {

    function PostsPager() {
      this.renderPosts = __bind(this.renderPosts, this);

      this.nearBottom = __bind(this.nearBottom, this);

      this.render = __bind(this.render, this);

      this.check = __bind(this.check, this);

    }

    PostsPager.prototype.contructor = function(page) {
      this.page = page != null ? page : 0;
      this.render();
      return $(window).scroll(this.check);
    };

    PostsPager.prototype.check = function() {
      if (this.nearBottom()) {
        return this.render;
      }
    };

    PostsPager.prototype.render = function() {
      alert(this.page);
      this.page++;
      $(window).unbind('scroll', this.check);
      return $.getJSON($('#feed').data('json-url'), {
        page: this.page
      }, this.renderPosts);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have poor spelling, `constructor` is the constructor method, `contructor` is just a poorly spelled method. You also need to say `@render()` to call `render` as a method on `this`. You want:

```
class PostsPager
  constructor: (@page=0)->
    @render()
    #...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eaQdv/

This spelling mistake means that your `contructor` was never called and that's why you never saw an error about an "unknown render variable" that would be caused by the missing `@`.

Comment: @Chris: That's nothing, just wait until you start making real mistaeks :)